# c# project with CI build - reference to Oracle extension causes build error

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

I have a C# app build in MS VisualStudio (2015) and it's checked in to a VisualStudio repository hosted for the company I work for. 
I defined a 'Build' profile on the VisualStudio server with 'Continuous Integration' on, so it builds every time there's a check in.
It's been working fine until now...

I had to add some code that called an Oracle Server, so in my code I have

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
...
```

and at the top

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
```

and in my Project I did:
`Add > Reference > Assemblies > Extensions > Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`

so, it all builds and runs on my development PC.

On the TeamFoundationServer however, the build fails now with message

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

on the `using` line of the source file.

I assumed that the server would include the Oracle extension because it's now referenced in the project file (which is checked in).  Is there another step I need to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assemblies listed in the `Extensions` list are ones provided by extensions you've installed into Visual Studio (my guess is you've installed the 'Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio' extension).

Because this extension hasn't been installed on your build server (and nor should it) the build server naturally complains that it can't find the reference.

The solution is to remove the reference you've added an instead add a reference to the NuGet package containing the Oracle driver. This looks to be the correct one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Your build server will then fetch the NuGet package as it would for any other assembly.

Comment: Does it imply I should never use 'References' and always use NuGet packages?

Comment: No - there are plenty of valid uses for manually adding references such as if you want to reference to another project within the same solution or if you are making use of a COM component. Generally however if you're referencing a 3rd party library then NuGet should be your preferred choice because all common build tools support it.